# " <= 0 " Not Preventing Negatives?

Tags: javascript, return-value, negative-number

**See:**

[**-WORKING EXAMPLE-**](http://jsbin.com/iRUYIbUV/1/edit?html,js,output)

**How to replicate my *problem:**

If you put all your bonus points into a stat except 1, and then CTRL-CLICK in the other stat, then the bonus value will go into the negative, when ***it should be stopping at 0**.

**Controls:**

- Left-Click = Allocate 1 point
- CTRL Left-Click = Allocate 5 points
- Right-Click = Take back 1 point
- CTRL Right-Click = Take back 5 points

**JavaScript:**

```
var Alexander =
    {
      Magic: "MagicVal",
      Attack: "AttackVal",
      Bonus: "BonusVal",
      Limits: {
        Magic:  {
          max: 100,
          min: 80
        },
        Attack: {
          max: 100,
          min: 80
        }
        }
    };

function table(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
}

function add(character, stat) //Allocates "1" with left-click//
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  if(newNumber > character.Limits[stat].max) return;
  var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
  if(BonusVal.value <= 0) return;
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 1;
  BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function subtract(character, stat) //Takes back "1" with right-click//
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 1;
  if(newNumber < character.Limits[stat].min) return;
  var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) + 1;
  BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function dump(e, character, stat) //Allocates "5" with CTRL+left-click//
{
  if (e.ctrlKey == 1 && e.which == 1) {
  console.log('met');
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 4;
  if(newNumber > character.Limits[stat].max) return;
  var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
  if(BonusVal.value <= 0) return;
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 4;
  BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}
}

function reclaim(e, character, stat) //Takes back "5" with CTRL+right-click//
{
  if (e.ctrlKey == 1 && e.which == 3) {
  console.log('met');
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 4;
  if(newNumber < character.Limits[stat].min) return;
    var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) + 4;
  BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: fyi you are missing the last parameter in your parseInt calls. This can lead to goofy results.

Comment: What's the point? Value is 1, positive, then you subtract 4 to it. Your condition works, logic is failing here... Try "if bonus < delta, set delta = bonus and bonus = 0"

Comment: @richadtz Answer solves everything for me. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: @MBillau I've actually tried adding the parameter, but it always breaks the application.  If you can show me a working example I would be interested.

Comment: @user2811882 - `parseInt(BonusVal.value, 10)`
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to replace ( in your `dump` method) this

```
  if(BonusVal.value <= 0) return;
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 4;
```

with this :

```
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 4;
  if(newBonus <= 0) return;
```

Comment: So simple!  Thank you for the example my friend.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are checking the existing value for Bonus before perfoming any adjustment to it.  Thus if the bonus were say 1 and you were trying to remove 5 from it, the check would show value at 1 and proceed with the math to change the value to -4.

My guess is that you will want to apply the math, and then check against 0 afterwards and adjust to 0 if value < 0.

Comment: The issue with adjusting to 0 is that the amount allocated would still be 5.  It solves the bonus value problem, but that's only half the problem.

Comment: I don't understand you amount allocate problem.  If you need to determine the actual amount allocated just subtract original value from new value after adjustment.

Comment: @richadtz Answer solves everything for me.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

the working example!...

http://jsbin.com/omigOti/1/edit

you need verify if the bonus will be negative... like this correction...

```
function add(character, stat) //Allocates "1" with left-click//
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  if(newNumber > character.Limits[stat].max) return;
  var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
  if(BonusVal.value <= 0) return;
  var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 1;
  if( newBonus < 0 ){ //try if is negative

    newBonus = 0; //and fix it
    newNumber = +(BonusVal.value);

  } 
  BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function dump(e, character, stat) //Allocates "5" with CTRL+right-click//
{
  if (e.ctrlKey == 1 && e.which == 1) {
    debugger;
    console.log('met');
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById(character[stat]);
    var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 4;
    if(newNumber > character.Limits[stat].max) return;
    var BonusVal = document.getElementById(character.Bonus);
    if(BonusVal.value <= 0) return;
    var newBonus = parseInt(BonusVal.value) - 4;
    if( newBonus < 0 ){ //try if is negative

      newBonus = 0; //and fix it
      newNumber = +(BonusVal.value);

    } 
    BonusVal.value = newBonus; 
    txtNumber.value = newNumber;
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue with adjusting to 0 is that the amount allocated would still be 5.  It solves the bonus value problem, but that's only half the problem.  The other half being that 5 points are magically created from thin air, which screws everything up.  @richadtz Answer solves everything for me. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: when you trigger the dump, the add are triggering too... you need trigger only one...

Comment: That's why I used 4 instead of 5.  It works the same :)  Non-issue, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: you can look this... maybe will solve your question http://jsbin.com/omigOti/5/edit

Comment: you can look this... maybe will solve your question http://jsbin.com/omigOti/6/edit only one method will solve your problem!...